# Icon shown after mouse movement in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a search box which on which i hide and show two classes one for search icon image and other for cross icon image like this:

```
<span id="search-icon" class="search-icon"></span>
    <input type="text" id="txtABFSearch" class="form-control mt17 right search-header form-control-header" maxlength="500" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Franchisee" />
    <div id="dvSearchResults" style="display: none;">
```

what i am doing in JS is when a user types in search icon class is removed from search-icon span and cross icon class is added like this:

```
$('#txtABFSearch').keyup(function (e) {
    var searchString = $('#txtABFSearch').val();
    if (jQuery.trim(searchString).length >= 1) {
        if (searchString != '') {
           $("#search-icon").addClass("cross-icon");
        $("#search-icon").removeClass("search-icon");
        }
    }

});
```

Every thing works fine on other browsers like chorme firefox but in IE when i type in icons only shown after mouse is moved over it.

Please see these two images.
[Before search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw9FD.png) [After search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQHSO.png)
My IE version is 11.309.16299.0 and my jquery version is 3.3.1

Comment: when does your `if(JQuery.trim..` invoked? onfocus? onclick? onblur?

Comment: Invoked on keyup. I have edited the question please see the updated version.

Comment: could you share your jquery version? i just saw... https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1758 well, thats for jqueries after 1.8.. it seem IE handles event differently.

Comment: My jquery version is 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer was not supporting your code. Try prefixes as well.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```